# bucle for no se ejecuta en paralelo

Tags: c++, mpi

Tengo un código en C++ que intento paralelizar con OpenMPI, consiste en buscar los números primos hasta un tope indicado:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <ctime> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    unsigned t0, t1;
    t0 = clock();
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    auto maximo = 1000000ul; //numero maximo a buscar
    // Criba secuencial
    std::vector<int> primos{ 2 }; // Añadimos el 2 al array para poder saltarnos los pares
    primos.reserve(maximo);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (auto posible_primo = 3ul; posible_primo < maximo; posible_primo += 2) {
        /* Comprobamos si es primo buscando si en el array hay algun
        numero primo que lo divida, pero solo hasta raiz de n. */
        const auto limite = sqrt(posible_primo);

        bool es_divisible = false;
        for (auto divisor : primos) {
            if (limite < divisor)
                break;
            if (es_divisible = !(posible_primo % divisor))
                break;
        }


        if (!es_divisible) {
            primos.push_back(posible_primo);
        }
    }

    for (auto primo : primos)
        std::cout << primo << ' ';
    t1 = clock();
    double time = (double(t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    cout << "\n\n\tExecution Time: " << time << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Tengo que paralelizar el bucle exterior (el que recorre los números desde 3 hasta el límite superior), para ello he utilizado `#pragma omp parallel for`

Cuando ejecuto el algoritmo, tarda lo mismo que si quito la sentencia paralela.

¿Qué hago mal? tampoco se cómo hacer para evitar las condiciones de carrera en la escritura del número primo en el vector.

Comment: Fíjate en tu administrador de tareas si usa los procesadores al mismo tiempo, también verifica que compilaste con los comandos adecuados

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que crear hilos de ejecución ni es una solución mágica ni tiene coste cero. Cada hilo necesita un espacio de memoria para su pila y su montón (*stack* y *heap*), configurar eso tiene un coste determinado que a veces supera el coste de computación que se paraleliza, con lo que en ocasiones puede resultar que una tarea ¡tarde más en completarse cuando se paraleliza!.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster sí, eso lo se, pero no se si el problema es que no está bien el código que he puesto para paralelizar o si es po lo que comentas, dado que calculo números grandes  y el coste en tiempo es el mismo

Comment: @XBoss lo que también puede estar pasando es que todos los hilos comparten el recurso `std::vector<int> primos` y se bloquean entre ellos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sí, pero no entiendo cómo se evita eso, los ejemplos que encuentro no los se aplicar, así que tenía la esperanza de que no pasase

Comment: Con omp no lo vas a evitar. Tienes que crear semáforos alrededor del recurso compartido. Pero no te servirá de nada, porque los datos son dependientes: para calcular un primo N, necesitas los primos anteriores a N, así que si en un hilo calculas de 0 a 99 deberás esperar a que ese tramo acabe para calcular de 100 a 299: o sea que será lo mismo que hacerlo secuencialmente.

Comment: Bueno, he dividido el problema en 4 trozos, cada uno con sus listado de primos, ha mejorado algo el rendimiento